# Eigendecomposition of a summation of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Can anyone tell me if there's a way to relate the eigendecomposition of the result of a summation of matrices with the eigendecomposition of those matrices?
More specifically:
If I have a matrix $K = \sum\limits_{m=1}^M a_m K_m$, $a_m \in R$.

How can I relate its eigendecomposition, $K = V \Lambda T^T$, with the eigendecomposition of the matrices in the summation, i.e. $K_m = V_m \Lambda_m V_m^T$?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing useful to say. Consider the decomposition $I=A+(I-A)$. There is no useful relation between the eigenvalues of $I$ and those of $A$.

Comment: You should probably have a look to the link given by Suvrit in comment to the question.